# How can I add token authentication to my nestJS app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, authentication, oauth-2.0, nestjs

I have a nestJS app that allows a user to interact with my MongoDB, mostly CRUD operations. However, this is hosted on Heroku which means that anyone can send requests and perform operations on my database.

What I would like to achieve is to have only users who have a valid token be able to use the API. The users would have to send their requests with a token `v1/search/errors?token=INSERTTOKENHERE`

However, all the docs I've read are getting a user to login to a frontend like you would login to Facebook or YouTube. I have a frontend but the users of the API will be applications and not people so I don't want them to have to interact with a frontend. Ideally, I can just generate a token for the application and then only apps with a token can interact.

I have searched far and wide and have not found anything like this but every public API I have used behaves like this. Any links to docs that explain how I can achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/express-sample-api-key-management

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia yeah that again assumes a login page. Also stormpath shut down in 2017...

Comment: first, generate the token and save it in your database. then create a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards). in the guard take the token from the request, and match it with your database data.

Answer (score -1):

Tokens are a way to identify unique and authenticated users. Login attempt is mandatory for creating a token. You need a Guard implemented to verify each user on API request. Login from a front end Application is not mandatory. You can login from postman sending the right body elements.